# ASCII art in C++

Tags: c++, ascii-art

I'm attempting to put in [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) in a C++ program and did so by manually printing each line, but the outcome was nothing like the ASCII art. It's like:

[image]

Does this occur because the characters are not recognizable by the prompt or have I not done it correctly?

Here is the ASCII art I'm trying to do:

```
_____/\\\\\\\\\________/\\\\\\\\\\\__________/\\\\\\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\_        
 ___/\\\\\\\\\\\\\____/\\\/////////\\\_____/\\\////////__\/////\\\///__\/////\\\///__       
  __/\\\/////////\\\__\//\\\______\///____/\\\/_______________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____      
   _\/\\\_______\/\\\___\////\\\__________/\\\_________________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____     
    _\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\______\////\\\______\/\\\_________________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____    
     _\/\\\/////////\\\_________\////\\\___\//\\\________________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____   
      _\/\\\_______\/\\\__/\\\______\//\\\___\///\\\______________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____  
       _\/\\\_______\/\\\_\///\\\\\\\\\\\/______\////\\\\\\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\_ 
        _\///________\///____\///////////___________\/////////__\///////////__\///////////__
```

Code:

```
cout << "_____/\\\\\\\\\________/\\\\\\\\\\\__________/\\\\\\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\_        \n";
cout << " ___/\\\\\\\\\\\\\____/\\\/////////\\\_____/\\\////////__\/////\\\///__\/////\\\///__       \n";
cout << "  __/\\\/////////\\\__\//\\\______\///____/\\\/_______________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____      \n";
cout << "  _\/\\\_______\/\\\___\////\\\__________/\\\_________________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____     \n";
cout << "    _\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\______\////\\\______\/\\\_________________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____    \n";
cout << "    _\/\\\/////////\\\_________\////\\\___\//\\\________________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____   \n";
cout << "      _\/\\\_______\/\\\__/\\\______\//\\\___\///\\\______________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____  \n";
cout << "       _\///________\///____\///////////___________\/////////__\///////////__\///////////__\n";
```

Comment: Show the code that is responsible for printing

Comment: It's literally "cout << "*ASCII LINE* \n"; for all the lines

Comment: you're missing the leading spaces and your lines break, seems easy to fix if you could actually see the code

Comment: I think using `cout << "blablabla" << endl;` instead of  `cout << "blablabla\n";` should work too... hard to say what endl type your `iostream` is using (I am not using it for decades) but my bet is `"\r\n"` ...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) are interpreted as single special or other characters, hence the strange output. `"\\"` means `'\'` for example.

You can use a raw string literal:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << R"(
_____/\\\\\\\\\________/\\\\\\\\\\\__________/\\\\\\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\_        
 ___/\\\\\\\\\\\\\____/\\\/////////\\\_____/\\\////////__\/////\\\///__\/////\\\///__       
  __/\\\/////////\\\__\//\\\______\///____/\\\/_______________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____      
   _\/\\\_______\/\\\___\////\\\__________/\\\_________________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____     
    _\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\______\////\\\______\/\\\_________________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____    
     _\/\\\/////////\\\_________\////\\\___\//\\\________________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____   
      _\/\\\_______\/\\\__/\\\______\//\\\___\///\\\______________\/\\\_________\/\\\_____  
       _\/\\\_______\/\\\_\///\\\\\\\\\\\/______\////\\\\\\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\_ 
        _\///________\///____\///////////___________\/////////__\///////////__\///////////__        
)" << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a0cb9ef52b31e4f)